# Android, ViewFlipper with GestureDetector in Tabhost

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-tabhost, gesturedetector

I wanted to make one tabhost and I wanted to add one viewflipper one activity.
This activity works with tabhost.
I've written but what does not work. Have anybody an idea how can I do that? I hope they understand what I wanted.

[image]

I wanted to use in this activitiy of the GestureDetector. I can change the pictures with button but with finger i cant.

Answer (score 2):

I have made it before. ( https://github.com/vancexu/AimTo/tree/master/src/com/hackingtrace/vancexu AimToActivity.java)
Just implement your own `GestureDetector` ,then in your tab activity register a  `OnTouchListener`

By the way, I also implement the slide animation, using `ViewFlipper` in `TabHost`

Some code in my `TabHostActivity`

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 180; 
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());

    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe, tab change to right
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.i("Gesture ", "right");
                if (currentView == maxTabIndex) {
                    currentView = 0;
                } else {
                    currentView++;
                }
                viewFlipperBody.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                viewFlipperBody.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                viewFlipperBody.setDisplayedChild(currentView);

            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.i("Gesture ", "left");
                if (currentView == 0) {
                    currentView = maxTabIndex;
                } else {
                    currentView--;
                }
                viewFlipperBody.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                viewFlipperBody.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                viewFlipperBody.setDisplayedChild(currentView);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(currentView);
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```